# Truncated sum of divisors bound

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, divisor-sum, divisor-counting-function

I am interested in an upper bound for 
$$
\sum_{\substack{d|N\\ d>A}}\frac{1}{d^3},$$
in particular, I can get the above to be 
$$\sum_{\substack{d|N\\ d>A}}\frac{1}{d^3}\ll \frac{\text{exp}\left(C \frac{\log(N)}{\log\log(N)}\right)}{A^3}$$
for some positive constant $C$. However I would like to do better. I think that the upper bound should be around 
$$ \frac{\log^C(N)}{A^3}$$
for some other positive constant $C.$

We also have that $A<N^{1/2}.$
References are welcome.